# ":" in the for() function

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment that involves a board. The base code is given for us to modify, but I don't understand what the `:` in the parameters of the for() means. Does it go through all the board (the `ArrayList`)?

```
private ArrayList<MovingElement> moveElems = new ArrayList<MovingElement>();

for (MovingElement mElement : moveElems) {
    mElement.step();
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2 Take a look at JLS..

Comment: And ":" is not a parameter. This is called 'syntax'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a special form of the `for` loop used to iterate over arrays and any [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which includes any [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

This is referred to as a *for-each* loop, as in: *for each element of a list*.

Read: `for (MovingElement mElement : moveElems)` as _for each `MovingElement` in the collection `moveElems_`.

See: [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop in Java.

For each element in `Arraylist` (or) array.

The element will be assigned to MovingElement mElement which is scoped to the for loop .

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this:

```
for (MovingElement mElement : moveElems) {
    // translates into English like this: 
    // for EACH MovingElement object in the ArrayList moveElems, 
    // do the following code:
    mElement.step();
}
```

It is a for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple foreach kind of loop, it will iterate through each of the elements in the given array.

In this case, MovingElement will be the type of the array, mElement will be the current element, and moveElems will be the actual array.

The ":" only separates between the two parts

So in your case, the loop will iterate through each of the elements in the ArrayList and use it's step() method.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a foreach or enhanced for loop in Java. The `':'` char separates the iteration variable type/name from the object to be traversed.

Here's a little [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) explaining its use, it's useful to know that it was introduced in the version 1.5 of the Java language. It's syntactic sugar, the same iteration behavior can be achieved by using a standard for loop and/or by using iterators.

The foreach loop can be used for iterating over the elements in an array, or over an object (typically a collection) that implements the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

Just for reference, the foreach statement is defined in section [§14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Java "for each" syntax. It is more or less equivalent to:

```
Iterator<MovingElement> iter = moveElems.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next().step();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For-each loop is intended to simplify the most common form of iteration, where the iterator or index is used solely for iteration, and not for any other kind of operation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

**-** What u have just come across is a known as extended for-loop  or more famously known as for-each loop.

`for( DataType variable : Iterable )`

**Eg:**

`for( String variable : arr )`

`arr` **-** Can be an array or Collections (ie Iterables), of type String

`s`   **-** will take each value of arr at every iteration and assign it to s